# DateAdd() function not working properly

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I want to use DateAdd() to calculate a new time but the results are confusing to me.

```
Dim lstZeit As Date 'lstZeit is 20:00:00 (8pm) 
Dim DatumEnd As Date

DatumEnd = DateAdd("h", 4, lstZeit)
```

The Result of `DatumEnd` is 31.12.1899 and not 24:00:00

I think there is a problem with the calculation. If i try 09:00:00 instead of 20:00:00 the result is correct (13:00:00).

Comment: `24:00:00` is the next day's `00:00:00`.

Comment: There is no 24:00:00 in .net

Comment: even 00:00:00 would be nice but as you can see the result is 31.12.1899.

Comment: When a `DateTime` has a time of `00:00:00` it isn't shown when you inspect it,but it's really there. You can check by using `ToString` on it

Comment: @Pikoh is right, use `TimeValue(DatumEnd)` to get the actual time

Comment: @gizlmo i dont need the actual time i need to add 4 hours to 8pm.

Comment: @rel0aded0ne I meant the actual time instead of 31.12.1899, use it after the DateAdd, it will show 00:00:00

Comment: Where is this "show" code that you keep referring to? The *result* of the `DateAdd` is correct, but 31.12.1899 and 00:00:00 are just 2 different ways to ***display*** the result. How are you using the result of this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

> The Result of DatumEnd is 31.12.1899 and not 24:00:00

That result is correct as there is no time of 24:00:00. 24 hours is 1 day, so your value is 1899-12-30 plus (20 + 4) hours => 1899-12-31.

If you wish to display extended count of hours, use a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```